Clickable Map Marker or Annotation
I want to show a sheet when a Marker or Annotation on a Map is clicked on, showing relevant information about the location. I have found zero resources on how to do this in SwiftUI, even though its a pretty standard behaviour in a lot of apps that utilise maps. I tried adding a tap gesture to a Marker but that was not allowed by SwiftUI.

You can make a tap gesture on the annotation label and then display a sheet based on the selected location.
struct ExampleLocation: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var locations: [ExampleLocation] = [ExampleLocation(name: "Location",
                                                                       latitude: 30,
                                                                       longitude: -180)]
    @State private var selectedLocation: ExampleLocation?
    
    var body: some View {
        Map {
            ForEach(locations) { location in
                Annotation("", coordinate: location.coordinates) {
                    Text("Your Marker")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedLocation = location
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedLocation) { location in
            Text(location.name)
        }
    }
}


Since you didn't provide any reproducible code, I can only give you fragmented bits as guidance.
You don't need the tap gesture on the Marker, you just need to bind the Map to a selection:
Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $selectedLocation) {

where $selectedLocation is a binding to a @State:
    @State private var selectedLocation: Location?


and where Location can be whatever type you use that you want to show information for.
The above code use the Map initializer with a position parameter, but there are other initializers available that also accept selection, if you use it differently.
Then, depending on your sheet logic, you use the $selectedLocation to display info as needed. Very likely, you'll have something like:
.sheet(item: $selectedLocation) {
    //your sheet code here...
}

There is some working code here that may be useful.
This Youtube video on MapKit and Marker selection may also be of help.
There is also this Youtube video: Custom Map Annotation Pins for SwiftUI MapKit Map

onTapGesture works with Annotation because you can have a custom View as the content.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct SelectedMapSample: View {
    @State private var selectedCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @State private var coordinates = (0...100).map { _ in
        CLLocationCoordinate2D.random()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: .constant(.automatic)){
            ForEach($coordinates) { $coordinate in
                Annotation(coordinate.description, coordinate: coordinate) {
                    Text(coordinate.description)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedCoordinate = coordinate
                            print("tapped\n\t \(coordinate.description)")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedCoordinate) { coordinate in
            Text(coordinate.description)
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.3)])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .fraction(0.3)))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SelectedMapSample()
}
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static func random() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let latitude = Array(stride(from: -90, through: 90, by: 0.5)).randomElement()!
        let longitude = Array(stride(from: -180, through: 180, by: 0.5)).randomElement()!

        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: @retroactive Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        description
    }
    public var description: String{
        "latitude: \(latitude)\nlongitude: \(longitude)"
    }
}

